# Проблема с распознаванием рода. Библиотека pymorphy2

Tags: python, pymorphy2

У меня есть такой код:

```
with open('russian_nouns.txt', encoding='utf-8') as F:
    nouns_lines = F.readlines()
    random_noun = random.choice(nouns_lines)
    parsed = morph.parse(random_noun)[0]
    print(parsed.tag.gender)
```

Я беру случайное слово из файла и хочу узнать его род и напечатать его. Но когда я запускаю код:

```
вывод: None
```

Вот, к слову, переменная parsed:

```
Parse(word='жирянка\n', tag=OpencorporaTag('UNKN'), normal_form='жирянка\n', score=1.0, methods_stack=((UnknAnalyzer(), 'жирянка\n'),))
```

Я пытался обратится только к самому слову, но получал ошибку:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tag'
```

Этот код работает исправно:

```
 parsed = morph.parse('шкаф')[0]

    print(parsed.tag.gender)
```

вывод:

```
masc
```

Если что просите дополнительной информации. Надеюсь вы проясните меня в этой проблеме. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: ну там же перевод строки в конце. "жирянка" и "жирянка\n" это разные слова!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно убирать переносы строк перед разбором слова:

```
import pymorphy2

morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()

word = 'жирянка\n'

p = morph.parse(word)
print(p)

word = word.strip()  # Убрать пробельные символы в начале и конце строки
p = morph.parse(word)
print(p)
print(p[0].tag.gender)
```

Вывод:

```
[Parse(word='жирянка\n', tag=OpencorporaTag('UNKN'), normal_form='жирянка\n', score=1.0, methods_stack=((UnknAnalyzer(), 'жирянка\n'),))]
[Parse(word='жирянка', tag=OpencorporaTag('NOUN,inan,femn sing,nomn'), normal_form='жирянка', score=1.0, methods_stack=((DictionaryAnalyzer(), 'жирянка', 8, 0),))]
femn
```

Видно, что после обрезки лишних символов слово вполне успешно разбирается.

Аналогичная проблема может возникнуть при попытке разбора не одного слова, а словосочетания или предложения. Pymorphy2 не предназначен для этого, нужно сначала разбить на отдельные слова (в том числе убрать знаки препинания), потом уже каждое слово отдельно разбирать.